# Maintain entity data model when column is removed from database that is used many places?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Assume that I have a entity data model I generated from my database. I use one of the columns throughout code in many places, but one day I decide that I don't need this anymore, so I remove it from the database and the places in code that reference this property from the entity data model are now broken.  Is the only solution to this is to go to each place and fix it or are there any strategies or tools that can assist in scenarios like this?

Comment: You mean tools that can example your program, figure out the intent of the code was and *fix it*?

Comment: this is what happens when you "stringly type" instead of "strongly type"

Comment: @Eranga: Given this is Entity Framework, it was probably strongly typed, problem is all the code that referenced that property now looks like `someObject.[property that no longer exists]` and it doesn't compile.

Comment: @R0MANARMY then u can refactor using something like `Resharper` but most probably it is like `DataField="FirstName"`

Comment: @Eranga: Refactor to what?  Suppose you have something like `string.Format("{0} - {1}", object.[field that doesn't exist], object.someField);`.  What's the correct thing to do, just remove the first parameter and have string formatting break?  Replace it with some other value?  Take out the whole line as it no longer makes sense?  You'll still have to make that call on a case by case bases, presumably everywhere there's a compiler error.

Comment: @R0MANARMY yes its not fool proof. But you can do "Safe Delete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is only practical for applications that haven't been released yet.  If an application has been released and this column already exists, it would not be removed or deleted. Existing customers may be depending on that column for data, it may be tied to application logic etc.  For compatability reasons, it wouldn't be removed.

If this is pre-production application (pre 1.0 release), any ORM solution should be able to recreate the logical and conceptable model(s) after the physical column in the database has been removed.  At that point, there may be some cleanup in the other layers of the application (UI, business, etc) that reference conceptable model in some fashion.   For example, the UI may need to be updated to remove the display of that data.  That would require some manual effort.

In general, it is better to keep it unless the application is in the early stages of development.

Answer (score 1):

As such, you haven't specified about data in column and need for removing it, so we have to talk in general terms.

If you can remove the column from database and yet has used it in many places at code then probably its computed column - In general, it means you can derive the same information from other data-points. So in your entity model, you should stop mapping the column to the database and rather replicate the logic in the code to compute meaning-full value for the property. Or you can create a view over the table and compute the column at database side and map your entity to the view instead of table.

In case, the column is not computed then removing the column from database means loss of data. And if that is acceptable then it essentially indicates the change in underlying business model where that data point become irrelevant. You have two choices here -

1. Go for it and change your code for not to use this property - it essentially means that you will adjusting  your code for business model/process change that you have to eventually do at some time.
2. Keep the column in database for some time but have a meaning-full default value. Mark the entity model property obsolete so that it will start giving warning. Take your time to make code changes, ultimate aim is to remove the property usage over a time and then remove the database column.